# Why does wave diffraction occur in vacuums?

Tags: waves, electromagnetic-radiation, soft-question, vacuum, diffraction

EM waves don't encounter any obstacles/apertures in a vacuum, so why would diffraction occur in the first place in a vacuum?

If diffraction does occur, then it would decrease an EM wave signal's intensity, so how are we able to detect EM waves?

Comment: This means, that the light rays are not parallel, that's why the diameter of the beam expands over distance at a certain angle, even in vacuum.

Comment: can you give an example when a plane wave propagating in vacuum diffracts without hitting an obstacle?